# Loyalty Cards - Companion App Required?

Tags: android, android-pay

Sorry for being vague here, I'm not 100% sure how to phrase my question.

I'm looking into creating a loyalty card for Wallet on iOS and for Android Pay on Android. I know how everything is done on iOS, but am a bit confused on the Android side.

I read through the guide provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/loyalty/tutorial#3-use-oauth-20-for-your-server-to-server-application), which states that I need `There are three essential pieces to a loyalty solution: Your server containing a web service, Google Wallet where loyalty information is stored, and the Google Wallet app used by users to access their loyalty information.`

Am I reading this correctly that in order to put a Loyalty Card, which will consist of a static member number that is generated at time of creation, I need to have an Android companion app?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have an Android companion app to integrate Save to Android Pay. It is the service that is used to generate loyalty card objects.
https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/
Most the documentation can be found there.

Comment: sharing Link is ok, until you have quoted the context from the post which will help the OP and future SO users as well. this will ensure your answer is valid even if link is broken